# UIPasteboard retrieving previous item

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipasteboard

I've got the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
NSString *string =  [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
```

The problem is that the pasteboard is returning what I've copied previously, not currently. Somehow it's hanging onto the previous item I've copied and returning that, and then next time around I get the item that I wanted and copied... strange behaviour.. any ideas?

**Edit**

I've got a solution using an observer, but not sure how elegant it is.. there seems to be some delay between copy and setting an item.. enough for it not to be set and for the previous one to be still on the UIPasteBoard.

Answer (score 0):

I have composed a little sample to your code for copy/paste behavior and it works as expected: selected text is printed to console after tapping on the button.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let textField = UITextField()
let copyButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)

@objc func copySelectedText() {

    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.copy(_:)), to: nil, from: self, for: nil)
    let copiedString = UIPasteboard.general.string

    print(copiedString)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    display(textField, copyButton)

    copyButton.setTitle("tap to copy selected text", for: .normal)
    copyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(copySelectedText), for: .touchUpInside)
}


private func display(_ textField: UITextField, _ copyButton: UIButton) {

    copyButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(copyButton)
    view.addSubview(textField)

    textField.backgroundColor = .white
    textField.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    copyButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    copyButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look and checking it out. The difference I see is that you're using UIResponder.copy - would that make a difference in the selector?

Comment: It will not. UIApplication is a subclass of UIResponder. So unless you don't override copy  method in UIApplication it makes no difference

Comment: Okay - wondering why there's a delay between copy / getting the string from the pasteboard - enough so that when I get it, it's what I had in there previously.. handoff an issue?

Comment: Not possible to reason without seeing the actual code you are having troubles with.